# File upload functionality in Visualforce vs Lightning Component

Tags: visualforce, lightning-aura-components, upload, apexinputfile

What is the maximum file upload limit when creating file upload solution in visualforce vs lightning considering governer limits as well.

Based on my understanding,

1. Using visualforce max size of file can be 10 MB (this is part of documentation for apex:inpuFile tag)
2. Using lightning component - based on Peter Knolle's blog post - 
   http://peterknolle.com/file-upload-lightning-component/
   max size of file can be 4.3 MB

Is this correct ? Can you please share your insight on uploading files in SFDC and file size limitations in each approach ?

Comment: Hi apn, I am also struggling with file upload using lightning component. Did you found any solution for that ? is is true that you cannot upload file more than 4.3 MB using lightning component? refer to below link for more details : http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/157024/uploading-file-in-contentversion-using-lightning-component